# MethodNotAllowed Exception on form submit

Tags: laravel, form-submit

> routes.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::get('/', function () {
  $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

   return view('tasks', [
    'tasks' => $tasks
   ]);
});


Route::get('Login', 'Login@index');
```

> View: loginform.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/blog/public/Login">

        <!-- Task Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
            {!! Form::label('usernamelabel','Username', ['class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('username', '', ['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'username']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            {!! Form::label('passwordlabel', 'Password', ['class'=>'form-control control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('password', '', ['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'password']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Add Task Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">

                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Login
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

> Controller: Login.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Http\Models\userloginModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Login extends Controller{

 protected $request;


 public function index(Request $request)
{
    echo view('login.loginform');

        $foo = new userloginModel();
        echo $foo->username = $request->username;
        echo $foo->password = $request->password;


 }


}
```

I have try all solutions from Stackoverflow and laracast but i failed to solve this please some one help me from this i am new with laravel..

Comment: Need to fix few things use `url('login');` in form `action` instead of `http://localhost/blog/public/Login` Secondly, try to change your route to `Route::get('login', 'LoginController@index');` then you have to return your view in index function instead of echo the view

Comment: Thanx for answer But I have change this two things action="{{url('login')}}" and change Route::get('Login', 'LoginController@index'); but still same error facing

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in method, u trying to make a post request and your route are receiving a get request, try this:

**Route**

```
<?php
//...
    Route::get('Login', 'Login@index');
    Route::post('Login', 'Login@login');
?>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
//...
     public function index()
    {
        return view('login.loginform');
     }
     public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $foo = new userloginModel();
        echo $foo->username = $request->username;
        echo $foo->password = $request->password;
     }
?>
```